# select query which will have return new position column in it

Tags: php, mysql

H guys

I just need a select query which will have return new position column in it i.e

i want the result to be

```
id       score     position
23       345       1
09       309       2
12       123       3
```

I tried this but didn't work

```
(SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position,
                           id, 
                           score  
                           FROM tabs 
                           ORDER BY score DESC");
```

position row was empty, please help using php

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position,
id, 
score  
FROM tabs, (SELECT @rownum:=0) AS initrownum
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Comment: Any idea to get just the one position based on an id -  i tried modyfying it to return a specific position based on an id but it failed

Comment: If you mean "just the row with the biggest score" you just need to add "LIMIT 1" to the original query

Comment: If you mean "given an id, what is the position" I'd recommend a different query structure. In this case you might want to have PHP make 2 queries: First "select * from tabs where id=...", then "select count(*)+1 as pos from tabs where score>[score from first query]"

Answer (score 0):

your query should be like :`SELECT id, score FROM tabs ORDER BY score DESC`
and your php:
`for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($result); $i++){
echo $i;
echo $result['id'][$i];
echo $result['score'][$i]
//br the line here
}`